Contact us form not sending email if we redirect the page to some other url
We have PWA Venia Storefront [ Reactjs on frontend ] . In Contact us page in our website, user enter all details and enter submit button, two things will happen :

We are displaying message : "Your message has been sent" in the same page and user will stay on same page.
we are passing those form information  to email id : abc@gmail.com


<Button
  priority="high"
  type="submit"
  disabled={isBusy}
  data-cy="submit"
  onClick={() => {
    submitContactUsForm();
  }}
>
  {}
  submit
</Button>;

useEffect(() => {
  if (response && response.status) {
    addToast({
      type: "success",
      message: formatMessage({
        id: "contactPage.submitMessage",
        defaultMessage: "Your message has been sent.",
      }),
      timeout: 5000,
    });
  }
}, [addToast, formatMessage, response]);
                   

Requirement :
Once User click on Submit, we need to redirect user to another page ( thank-you ) instead of keeping in same page. So i have done below changes and now user redirecting to another page :
                          `<Link to="/thank-you">
                            <Button
                                priority="high"
                                type="submit"
                                disabled={isBusy}
                                data-cy="submit"
                                className='submit-button'
                                onClick={()=>{

                                    submitContactUsForm()

                                }}
                            >
                                {}
                                submit
                            </Button>
            </Link>`

Issue :
Email is not Triggering
Here is the complete code : https://pastebin.com/aZpFH2F7

write your email sending code if it not sent by default.

@AfzalArshad custom code send to email is already written here : https://pastebin.com/aZpFH2F7 , only thing is if the submit form is in same page, than email will deliver, if we redirect form to some other page, than only email not send

write redirect code after email sending code

@AfzalArshad thanks for showing me the right path. is it possible for you to give me an updated code as i am beginner in reactjs

Do you mean redirect code?

@AfzalArshad redirect is already working, i just want to send the email after form submit

this task is for a backend developer, you can also search how to send emails in magento2, and you will find plenty of code.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
